# How can i combine two ModelForms in a single django views

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Goodday everyone, so i have two models, one of which has a foreignkey field pointing to the other and i have model forms for each model class and in my views.py, i would like to make the model with the foreignkey point at the other model

i made a modelforms (CharacterForm and RoleForm) in my forms.py which would show all fields but in my html, i would hide the player field (a foreignkey which points to the other model) so in my views.py i would automatically make the newly created character the player.

## models.py

```
class Character(models.Model):
    #some fields

class Role(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='the_player')
```

## views.py

```
    def NewRole(request):
        if request.method == 'POST'
            form = CharacterForm()
            formset = RoleForm()
            if all([form.is_valid, formset.is_valid]):
                role_player = form.save()
                formset.player = role_player
                formset.save()
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = CharacterForm()
            formset = RoleForm()
            return render(request, 'new_role.html', {'form':form, 
                'formset':formset})
```

i just wanted the player field under the role model to point at the Character model the user just created and i dont know the best way to do it. i thought this would work but i keep getting ForeignKey Constraint error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error, because you did *not* set the value of the `player` to the *instance* of that object, and hence the `player` field is still `None` when you create the object.

You can exclude this from your `RoleForm`, like:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Character, Role

class CharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Character

class RoleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        exclude = ('player', )
```

Next in your view, you construct the two forms, and you can link the `Character` once it is saved to the instance of the `Role` object you are constructing, like:

```
from app.forms import CharacterForm, RoleForm

def new_role(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        cform = CharacterForm(request.POST)
        rform = RoleForm(request.POST)
        if cform.is_valid() and rform.is_valid():
            character = cform.save()
            rform.instance.player = character
            rform.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        rform = CharacterForm()
        cform = RoleForm()
    return render(request, 'new_role.html', {'rform': form, 'cform': cform})
```

in your template, you can simply render this as:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-new-role-view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ rform }}
    {{ cform }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```